# I could not very GitHub 2FA

Tags: github

Just noticed today I could not access Github on web browser anymore. It asked me to every 2FA by two-factor authenticator (TOTP) app or browser extension but I am not sure how to do that.

I tried "Reconfigure 2FA on this account" and select "GitHub Mobile" in "Preferred 2FA method" section but no luck
Any ideas what should I do for now?
[image]

Comment: If you haven't already, download a TOTP authenticator app on your mobile device. Popular options include Google Authenticator, Authy, and Microsoft Authenticator. These apps generate time-based codes used to complete the 2FA process.

Comment: @ImanMohammadi: I dowloaded Google Authenticator, what should I do next now? (Sorry I am not familiar with this)

Comment: On the Settings page, find the "Security" tab on the sidebar. Under "Two-Factor Authentication", click on "Set up two-factor authentication". You'll be presented with options like 'Text message' or 'Authenticator app'. Since you have Google Authenticator, choose the 'Authenticator app' option. GitHub will display a QR code on your computer screen. Use Google Authenticator to scan this code. This links your GitHub account to the app. After scanning the QR code, Google Authenticator will provide a 6-digit code. Enter this code on GitHub's website where prompted. @mavien

Comment: Sure. I just added it as an answer. @mavien

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you haven't already, download a TOTP authenticator app on your mobile device.

Popular options include Google Authenticator, Authy, and Microsoft Authenticator. These apps generate time-based codes used to complete the 2FA process.

Then proceed with the following tasks sequentially:

1. On the Settings page, find the "Security" tab on the sidebar.
2. Under "Two-Factor Authentication", click on "Set up two-factor authentication". You'll be presented with options like 'Text message' or 'Authenticator app'.
3. Since you have Google Authenticator, choose the 'Authenticator app' option. GitHub will display a QR code on your computer screen.
4. Use Google Authenticator to scan this code. This links your GitHub account to the app. After scanning the QR code, Google Authenticator will provide a 6-digit code.
5. Enter this code on GitHub's website where prompted