Github mobile app sign in with 2fa on new phone
I've searched the internet for hours and been trying to solve this with no luck.
I've got an old phone and a new phone, and the old phone has internet and has my account and I know my account credentials and I also have access to a PC.
When I go to sign in to the mobile app on my new phone, I see a screen that says 2fa and asks for an auth code, and has options for using a passkey or a recovery code.

I see nowhere in the mobile app on my old phone (believe me, I've looked) for an auth code or pass key. I found a similar answer on SO that said to sign in to the website on PC and go to settings > password and auth and create a passkey. I did so (which required an auth code that popped up on the app on my old phone and also required PC password) and created a passkey.

The mobile app only allows for numbers for the auth code, I see no way to access the actual passkey (from screenshot above) and clicking "use your passkey" simply pops up with a screen that says to click a button when ready, and clicking the button pops up with a message that says "no passkeys available" and closing it says "authentication failed."
Surely I can't be the only one to get a new phone and want to sign in to the official GitHub app, and I know my username and password and have access to the mobile app. Does anyone know how I can sign in to the app on the new phone?

I have already read https://stackoverflow.com/questions/77799241/i-could-not-very-github-2fa and https://docs.github.com/en/authentication/securing-your-account-with-two-factor-authentication-2fa/configuring-two-factor-authentication as well as several others and nothing works

After trying many many times over several HOURS, the bottom area that says "Having problems?" added an option for "Use GitHub Mobile" which was NEVER there before in every single attempt I made before going back for several hours. I clicked it, a number was shown, and I entered the number on my old phone.
Issue is resolved. By far the worst 2fa experience of my life, and not even close, and I know I'd be completely locked out without my old phone.
